# How to do a non-greedy match

Tags: python, regex

Currently my regex below is matching comment within a comment aswell,for example for below input it matches both test1 and test2....how to match only test2?

```
import re
string="""
/*
 * devkit (c) 2012-2013, ARM-3.4. aLL DATA conf.
 *

 *
 */
/*
 * devkit (c) 2012, ARM-3.4. aLL DATA conf.
 *
 *
 */

#ifndef code_abc_WDI_H
#define code_abc_WDI_H
"""
text="devkit \(c\) 2012, ARM-3.4. aLL DATA conf"

pattern = re.compile(r'/\*.*?'+ re.escape(text) + '.*?\*/', re.DOTALL)
print re.sub(pattern, "", string)
```

OUTPUT:-

```
/*
 * devkit (c) 2012-2013, ARM-3.4. aLL DATA conf.
 *

 *
 */

#ifndef code_abc_WDI_H
#define code_abc_WDI_H
```

Comment: Can you provide an example that is valid python code (that is, just define the strings you are giving to `re.match` specifically?)

Comment: im assuming `test2` is a string.

Comment: Moral of this story: include your input and output, don't make assumptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you double-escape the `\(` and `\)` input text, so you don't match your input:

```
>>> re.escape(text)
'devkit\\ \\\\\\(c\\\\\\)\\ 2012\\,\\ ARM\\-3\\.4\\.\\ aLL\\ DATA\\ conf'
```

Redefine `text` as:

```
text="devkit (c) 2012, ARM-3.4. aLL DATA conf"
```

You'll need to use a negative look-arounds to match anything that is *not* the `/*` or `*/` comment opening and closing characters:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'/\*(?:[^/]|(?<!\*)/)*?' + re.escape(text) + r'(?:[^/]|/(?!\*))*?\*/')
```

So, this will match `/*` followed by 0 or more characters (non-greedy) that are *not* a `/` slash, *or* they are a slash but only if not preceded by a `*`. On the other end of the string we do the same for the `/*` pattern; slashes allowed but only if not followed by a `*`.

There is no need for `re.DOTALL` anymore, since we don't use the `.` dot operator anymore.

This then works correctly:

```
>>> text = "devkit (c) 2012, ARM-3.4. aLL DATA conf"
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'/\*(?:[^/]|(?<!\*)/)*?' + re.escape(text) + r'(?:[^/]|/(?!\*))*?\*/')
>>> pattern.sub("", string)
'/*\n * devkit (c) 2012-2013, ARM-3.4. aLL DATA conf.\n *\n\n *\n */\n\n\n#ifndef code_abc_WDI_H\n#define code_abc_WDI_H\n'
>>> print pattern.sub("", input)
/*
 * devkit (c) 2012-2013, ARM-3.4. aLL DATA conf.
 *

 *
 */


#ifndef code_abc_WDI_H
#define code_abc_WDI_H
```

Comment: @Martjin - i updated the code with a case where i am having the problem,the output should remove the comment /*
 * devkit (c) 2012, ARM-3.4. aLL DATA conf.
 *
 *
 */ but its not

Comment: Thats my whole problem..i dont want to delete the whole comment,following comment should stay /*
 * devkit (c) 2012-2013, ARM-3.4. aLL DATA conf.
 *

 *
 */

Comment: @ Martijn Pieters - I edited a while back..it does have 2 valid comments with /*...*/